# If all endogenous variables are I(1), and if just two of them are cointegrated, can I incorporate its cointegration in the VAR model?

Tags: vector-autoregression, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

Suppose a **VAR(p)** model containing $s$ endogenous variables such that $Y_{t} = (y_{1t}, \ \ldots, y_{st})$. It was verified that, for all $i \in \{1, \ \ldots, s\}$, $y_{it} \sim I(1)$. In addition, it was verified by means of Engel-Granger test that $y_{1t}$ and $y_{2t}$ are cointegrated time series such that, given $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha y_{1t} + \beta y_{2t} \sim I(0)$. But this is not true for any other pair of endogenous variables; and this is not true, generally speaking, for the $s$-vector $Y_{t}$. As far as I know, since the nonstationary time series in $Y_{t}$ are not cointegrated, I am not allowed to use a **VECM**. My question is as follows: is there any way to include $y_{1t}$ and $y_{2t}$ as cointegrated time series and, accordingly, to continue using a **VAR(p)** model? Otherwise, ignoring cointegration, the model would be a **VAR(p)** with $s$ endogenous variables $(\Delta y_{1t}, \ \ldots, \Delta y_{st})$.

P.S. There are theoretical reasons which justify the fact that $y_{1t}$ and $y_{2t}$ are cointegrated time series.